# Function "writeFile(String Text)" Doesn't work the second time used

Tags: java, save, filewriter, printwriter

Before you call this a duplicate, please acknowledge the following facts:

1. There are no boolean values.
2. After I read the text files MANUALLY, they were missing the second String supposed to be written to the file.

Here is the code that is supposed to matter:

```
package StorageBox;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StorageBox02 {
    String FileName;
    PrintWriter pw;
    Scanner sc;
    public StorageBox02(){

    }
    public StorageBox02(String FileName) {
        this.FileName = FileName;
    }
    public void writeFile(String Text) throws IOException{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FileName);
        pw = new PrintWriter (fw);
        pw.write(Text + "\t");
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

The second string is what is intended to happen when I run the `writeFile` method twice.

Comment: what second string? both of your methods perform exactly one write to a file (without append) then close it. calling either of those methods will overwrite anything previously written.

Comment: Not what you asked but .... it seems redundant to have two methods with identical content.  Just have one of the two methods, and call it twice.

Comment: True. I was desperate so I tried anything I could think of; not much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I read the text files MANUALLY, they were missing the second
>   String supposed to be written to the file.

Seems like you are trying to append to the previously written file. In that case, you need to open the file in append mode by passing `true` to the `PrintWriter`.

For Example, `new PrintWriter(fw, true);`